# fatal errors swift unexpected nil

Tags: ios, swift, null

I've searched far and wide and no one can seem to explain what I'm doing wrong. Here's my source. I have no idea what is going wrong and I've looked at my connections, references, etc. Nothing is able to help. I've done everything identical including the ViewController, TableView etc.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var items = ["One", "Two"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myTableView.registerClass(UITableView.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = self.items [indexPath.row]

    return cell;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your error and where does it occur?

Comment: The error happens when I try to run the app, it fails on startup and gives me an error on self.myTableView.registerClass(UITableView.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self

when I comment them out the app runs normally up until I click my button to segue to the ViewController containing the TableView

Comment: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and it gives me a bad instruction error for both those lines of code

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to be registering your custom `UITableViewCell` class, not `UITableView.self`.

Comment: what should the code be changed to? or do I need to change things in Storyboard?

Comment: If you haven't made a custom cell subclass, use `UITableViewCell.self`.

Comment: haven't done anything special, working on tutorials and when changed to UITableViewCell.self in that line it still fails on the same part with the same error

Comment: Solved it. had to make my Cell basic, not custom and it was a lot of trial and error. Thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableViewCell.self instead